# Two actions on a function in Laravel, possible?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 users roles in my application, **admin** and **former**.

The admin can create several formers...

[image]

If, I connect me with the ID 1 ? I retrieve the information of the former.

[image]

So, my function index() allows to retrieve id of the user

```
public function index()
{   
    if($has_role = auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')){
        $formers = Former::first()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers'));
    } else{
        $formers = Former::where('email', Auth::user()->email)->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers'));
    }
}
```

Well, for the user **admin**, I would like to create a search bar...

[image]

I had created **before** a function index() and which worked

```
public function index(Request $req)
{
    if ($req->search == "") {
        $formers = Former::paginate(5);
        return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers'));
    } else {
        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);

        $formers = Former::where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $validated['search'] . '%')->paginate(5);
        $formers->appends($req->only('search'));
        return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers'));
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to adapte my 2 actions in a function, is it possible according you?

Do you think that I can get the **user_id** and make a **search bar** in the same function?

Thank you

Comment: Is your question how make the "search bar" only visible to the admin user? Do you mean `$req->input('search')` instead of `$req->search`? And `Former::first()->paginate(5);` makes not much sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is the following:

- Add one action which serves both roles with data.
- Display the search only to admins, but ignore this fact on the server-side as it doesn't matter from a security perspective whether non-admins can search or not. They are limited to their result anyway.

Basically, this is achievable in the following way:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request)
{   
    $user = $request->user();

    $formers = Former::query()
        ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('email', $user->email);
        })
        ->when($request->has('s'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('nom', 'like', '%'.$request->input('s').'%');
        })
        ->paginate(5);

    return view('admin.formers.index', compact('formers'))
        ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
}
```

You can then in your view simply use the `$display_search` variable to decide whether or not you want to display the search:

```
@if($display_search)
  <form method="post" action="...">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Type to search...">
  </form>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tested your code but the search bar does not work. I don't  get the name of the trainer. I always have all the formers. However, I like the display_search.

Comment: You changed the `action` of the form, right? The HTML part was just an example to give you an idea about `$display_search`, it doesn't work out of the box this way.

Comment: Maybe also replace `$request->has('s')` with `$request->filled('s')` to avoid adding a constraint on empty search values.

Comment: In my HTML I have this? `@if($display_search)
        <form class="form-inline active-cyan-4">
    <div class="input-group add-on">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Recherche..." name="display_search" type="text">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  @endif` concernant `name=` I add `"display_search"` ?

Comment: Well if you change the name of the input, you also need to change it in your code. I would use something different than `display_search` though. `display_search` is a boolean flag to toggle the search. The search value itself should be something else like `s` or `search` like in your question. Don't forget to change the `$request->input('search')` and `$request->has('search')` part!

Comment: Thank you a lot Namoshek. Sorry, it was good. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#registering-policies) with a search method:

```
public function search($user)
{
    if ($user->isAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

now you may just edit your blade

```
@can('search')
  <form method="post" action="/search">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Recherche...">
  </form>
@endcan
```

If you want to give search access to other users as well, you only have to modify the policy.