# using a foreign key or not?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table named 'Feedbacks' with 5 fields:

```
('id', 'user_id', 'instruction', 'description', 'fk_eleve')
```

The admin can create several recordings, here is a screenshot.

Here, I have a recording which is `Menier Jeremy` it's the student

[image]

In my rubric 'Eleves' (english: Student) we can see several recordings:

Here, `Menier Jeremy` has like email address `test@gmail.com`.

[image]

`Menier Jeremy` wants to connect...

[image]

There are 2 rubrics for now:
- Student Profil and Feedback

[image]

the user `Menier Jeremy` can see his profil

[image]

However, when the user wants to see his 'feedback'.

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Field Field 'email' unknown in where (SQL: select count (*) as aggregate fromreturnswhere email= test@gmail.com)

I have a problem with the email ?

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    $user = $request->user();

    $feedbacks = Feedback::query()
        ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('email', $user->email);
        })
        ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->join('eleves', 'feedbacks.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')
                ->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')
                ->where('eleves.nom', 'like', '%'.$request->input('search').'%');
        })
        ->paginate(5);

    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'))
        ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
}
```

Do know you where is the problem?

Thank you a lot

Edit code @Watercayman

When, the user `Jeremy Menier` is connected, I see several recordings:

[image]

I have to retrieve only ID n° 1

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {   
    $user = $request->user();

    $feedbacks = Feedback::query()
    ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
        \Auth::user()->load('feedbacks');
        $feedbacksForThisUser = \Auth::user()->feedbacks;
    })
    ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
     $query->join('eleves', 'feedbacks.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')->where('eleves.nom','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%');
     })
    ->paginate(5);

    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'))
        ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
}
```

My model **User**:

```
public function feedbacks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Feedback', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

My model **Feedback**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to filter based on the email address? What is stored in `fk_eleve`? If it is the `id` of a user, you can simply filter on this instead (which is faster as well).

Comment: @Namoshek: I want the user to login via their email address. I edited my first message

Comment: What has that to do with the question? I'm confused.

Comment: @user11124425 The user can login via their email without having that be their primary key. You don't want email as the primary key - if they change their email address all your records would become disconnected from them.

Comment: @Namoshek: Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can get the email for the users that have provided feedback using the FK.  But I don't think you need all of the query you are using.  I think you can make this much simpler.  Because the user has a relation with the `Feedback` model (I assume through an `Eleve` model), you can simply eager load the relationship using the name search if you wish:

```
// Note I have removed the query() method you had in your original query

$feedbacks = Feedback::with('eleves', function ($query) use($request)             
    $query->orderBy('eleves.nom','asc')->where('eleves.nom','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%');
 })->paginate(5);
```

To simplify the explanation I've removed the `where` from the query.  To demonstrate I'll just use an if check before the query - you can make this more complex if you wish, but it is a little easier to see this way.

Something like:

```
if($request->has('search'){  do the query above } 
else { $feedbacks = Feedback::with('eleves')->paginate(5); }
```

Then, because you have pulled the relations, you can then just get the email from any `eleves` that have been loaded:

```
 $feedback->first()->eleve->email
```

So if you use the `$feedbacks` in a loop in your **blade** file:

```
 @foreach($feedbacks as $feedback)
    {{ $feedback->eleve->email }} 
 @endforeach
```

Comment: In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544469/two-actions-on-a-function-in-laravel-possible), the OP asked if it is possible to show different contents based on the user role. That's why there is a filter based on the users email address.

Comment: Interesting.  I think for the purpose of this question, it may be easier to explain the basics that he wants as described in this one... then, he can combine the FK email solution with the previous question, if this is still his intent.

Comment: Well, if the requirement mentioned in this question had been part of the other question, I'd have provided him with the appropriate query right away. But I guess we have to do it in steps. :)

Comment: @Watercayman: olalalalalala, sorry Watercayman, I edited my first message. Is it understandable now? Sorry,  for the time you took to write to me.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think because of the edit, the question is pretty different than what was first asked, so I'll add another answer rather than try to convey this in the comments.

I think you are asking that when the user tries to see his `feedbacks`, you are getting the SQL error.  If the user is selecting the feedback option, it may only be the single user that is looking for his own `feedbacks`.  I suggest you change your query to the reverse (pull the `feedbacks` from the user instead of pulling all the `feedbacks` and then getting user to match):

```
\Auth::user()->load('feedbacks');
$feedbacksForThisUser = \Auth::user()->feedbacks;
```

Or if you want to get another user's `feedbacks` (and the user has permission to see them), just query on that user:

```
$user = User::with('feedbacks')->find($idOfUserYouWantToSee);
$feedbacks = $user->feedbacks;
```

Same thing goes for if you want to search for `feedbacks` from a user with a specific name:

```
$user = User::with('feedbacks')->where('nom','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%')->first();
$feedbacksForSearchedUser = $user->feedbacks;
```

The key is to forget about the emails - the relationship will link all `feedbacks` to the user.  You don't need to join, or query on the email.  You always have it on the `$user` object. (i.e. `$user->email` will always work).

If you want to see ALL `feedbacks` from ALL users, this isn't really any harder, just query all users and eager load the `feedbacks` relationship:

```
$users = User::with("feedbacks")->get();
```

Then in your blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  // If you want to display only a special set of users to the Auth::User(), then do an if-check here
  @if(\Auth::user()->hasPerm("someperm") && $user->isInSomeCategory) 
      @foreach($user->feedbacks as $feedback)
         {{ $feedback->text // or whatever the field you want to show }}
      @endforeach
 @endif  // The if check is totally optional in this - just giving you an example
@endforeach
```

EDIT:  to show a simple index()

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {      
      if(!\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
         \Auth::user()->load('feedbacks');
         $feedback = \Auth::user()->feedbacks;
      }
      elseif($request->has('search')) {
         $user =  User::with('feedbacks')->where('nom','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%')->first();
         $feedbacks = $user->feedbacks;
     }

    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
}
```

Note: to make this as simple as possible, I also removed:

```
->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
```

You can check this on the Blade page because `\Auth::user()` is already loaded automatically.

Comment: I tested your codes, it works half. I no longer have error messages. (thank you), except that I have several records that are displayed. (the other students) Normally I only need to see the records of the logged in user. If you still have an idea do not hesitate. I have edited my first message

Comment: Well... half working is progress - at least we solved the error ;)  If you are seeing feedbacks that are not associated with the logged in user, please double check your relationship on the **User** model and the FK on the **Feedback** model.  If the **Feedback** model has a `user_id` and the **User** model is `hasMany` this should work.  If the `user_id` is set correctly on each `feedback`, this should only show the logged in user's feedbacks.

Comment: I always have the same problem. I have edited my first message with mes relationship. Normally it's correct no?I always have the same problem. I have edited my first message with mes relationship. Normally it's correct no?

Comment: Oh shoot - wait, are you using the code in your index(), or the code I wrote?  The code in your index() is not precise, and is causing the extra people.  That join is bringing in too much.  Try removing that whole block and just put in the lines I wrote.  You can add an if-check before the query to see if the Auth::user has the perm to see.   Wait -I'll EDIT my answer to include the simple index()

Comment: I tried several things for an hour, I still have the same problem. It's okay, I'll continue tomorrow night ... Thank you very much Watercayman for your help and the time you have spent for me. Half of my problem is solved. I am very happy.